# Making an excel VBA macro to change dates and format

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a complete novice at macros but I've had trouble finding the exact solutions I need, and more trouble combining them. I get this raw data report which needs a couple of changes before I can input it into our master data set for reporting. These things need to happen (please refer to the picture):

1. The date needs to be expressed in the formation "mmm-yy". I've tried to add "01/" to make "01/04/2017" (I'm Australian so this is the 1st of April), but for some reason it automatically changes it to 04/01/2017. Ultimately, I need 04/2017 to go to Apr-17 for all data in the column
2. "Medical Div" change to "Medical" and "Mental Health Div" change to "Mental Health" - i've already sorted a macro for this, but not sure how to combine it with another macro for the other functions I'm wanting.

If anyone can help providing code or links to good resources which will allow me to perform all these functions at once with one macro that would be great.

Thanks

[image: Raw data]

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with Power Query instead of VBA. Power Query is a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013 and built into Excel 2016 as "Get and Transform". Conceptually, the steps are:

- Load the data
- insert a new column with a formula that combines the text "1/" with the column Month-Year
- change the type of the new column to Date
- remove the old Month-Year column
- select the Division column
- replace " Div" with nothing
- Save the query

When new data gets added to the original data source, just refresh the query. All this can be achieved by clicking icons and buttons in the user interface. No coding required.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for point 2, how about recording a macro and using Find and Replace twice?
This should combine them into a macro for you. Then you can copy paste that elsewhere.

As for the date, Excel has an predisposition to convert to US format. Try this first (assuming "Month-Year" column is B)

```
Range("B2") = DateValue(Range("B2"))
```

Then apply formatting later.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub mySub()
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Dim myFind1, myFind2 As Variant
    Dim myReplace1, myReplace2 As Variant

    'This will get the number of rows with value in the sheet
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'This is for the first find and replace. It will search all cells with exact value of "Medical Div" in the sheet and change it to "Medical".
    myFind1 = "Medical Div"
    myReplace1 = "Medical"

    'This is for the second find and replace. It will search all cells with exact value of "Mental Health Div" in the sheet and change it to "Mental Health".
    myFind2 = "Mental Health Div"
    myReplace2 = "Mental Health"

    'This will loop through the entire column with the date that needs to have the format mmm-yy. It will convert the 04/2017 to date format first before making it Apr-17.
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set myRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        For Each r In myRng
            r.Value = CDate(r.Value)
        Next r
    End With

    myRng.NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"

    'This will loop through the active worksheet and apply the find and replace declared above.
    For Each mySheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        mySheet.Cells.Replace what:=myFind1, Replacement:=myReplace1, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        mySheet.Cells.Replace what:=myFind2, Replacement:=myReplace2, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next mySheet

End Sub
```

Here is a code that you could try.

- It will change the date format of the column with Month-Year to
  "Apr-17" regardless of the current date format.
- It will also find and replace the Medical Div and Mental Health Div
  to "Medical" and "Mental Health".

You will need to change the range to suit your needs. I have set the column for the month-year to column A. You must change it to column B if that is where your dates are.

This is my data before running the macro:

[image]

Here is my data after running the macro:

[image]

Comment: hmm this still isn't working on my dates. They still just stay as 04/2017. The value in these cells by the way is simply "04/2017" for all cells in the column

Comment: I edited the code and added a loop to change text values into date values first before changing the date format. It is working on my end with values as 04/2017. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately the dates convert to "4/1/17" and not "Apr-17". I feel this may have something to do with my region (Australia) so may be hard to come to a solution if you're from US for example. If I type "04/2017" into a fresh sheet it automatically turns it to "Apr-17" and assigns the 1st as the day. Perhaps maybe a bunch of if-then type commands to rewrite the whole cell with whichever of the relevant 12 months would be an easier approach?